# При использовании NAT запросы к WCF проходят не корректно

Tags: c#, wcf, nat

Есть служба WCF, она хостится на порту 8888.

При использовании NAT 
outside 8888, inside 8888 - проходит отлично.
outside 2145, inside 8888 - проходит с ошибкой.
outside 5416, inside 8888 - проходит с ошибкой.

Т.е., если использовать одинаковые порты на входе и выходе запросы проходят.
Если они разные, тогда нет.

**Служба**

Байндинг службы

```
  private static WSHttpBinding Setbinding()
    {
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        return binding;
    }
```

**Клиент**

Код запроса

```
  int PortNumber =2145;//или 5416 или 8888
  client = new PServiceClient(GetBinding(), 
  new EndpointAddress(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/PService/", "168.211.65.22", PortNumber)));
  ...
  //Проверка коннекта
  bool res = client.Connect();
```

Байндинг клиента

```
private WSHttpBinding GetBinding()
        {
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            timeout = TimeOut.GetTimeOut();
            return binding;
        }
```

Почему у меня не работают корректно запросы к службе при использовании NAT?

Comment: @PavelMayorov  я добавил в вопрос код.

Comment: @PavelMayorov. Допустил опечатку пока переносил код. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я ошибся при формулировке вопроса, спасибо за участие. Я исправил.
т. е. я хочу подцепиться к службе на 192.168.1.10:8888, через внешний ip 168.211.65.22:2145.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70771/discussion-between-cuprumbur-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: Все, теперь понятно что у вас произошло.

Comment: Или нет, не понимаю... В общем, попробуйте решения из моего ответа, если дело и правда в этом - то все нормально, иначе надо будет дальше думать.

Answer (score 4):

Вы используете WSHttpBinding - а эта привязка подразумевает использование стандарта WS‑Addressing, который в свою очередь передает адрес принимающей стороны в заголовке To.

Честно говоря, я не знаю зачем вообще в веб-сервисах, где отправитель и получатель сообщения всегда известны, использовать WS‑Addressing. Выглядит как глупость, и именно из-за нее SOAP считают довольно "тяжелым" протоколом.

Поэтому самый простой способ - отказаться от WSHttpBinding и перейти на BasicHttpBinding, там такой проблемы нет.

---

Если же вам требуется именно WSHttpBinding - то есть три пути.

Самый правильный с точки зрения стандартов - рассказать серверу какой у него реальный адрес:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
var internalUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.10:8888/PService/");
var externalUri = new Uri("http://168.211.65.22:2145/PService/");

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(foo);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), binding, internalUri);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFoo), binding, address: externalUri, listenUri: internalUri);
```

Я добавил две конечные точки чтобы сервер мог принимать как прямые запросы так и запросы через NAT.

Но хардкодить адреса - не лучшая идея, все же такие вещи лучше выносить в код:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApplication.Foo">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication.IFoo" address="http://192.168.1.10:8888/PService/" />
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication.IFoo" address="http://168.211.65.22:2145/PService/" listenUri="http://192.168.1.10:8888/PService/" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Тут главное - не перепутайте, `address` - это то что сервер будет ждать в заголовке To, сюда попадает тот адрес который видит клиент; `listenUri` же - этот тот адрес который реально слушает сервер.

---

Альтернативный вариант - обучить клиент передавать правильные заголовки. Этот вариант не очень хороший, поскольку раскрывает перед клиентом внутреннюю структуру сети сервера. Но для полноты картины я его тоже приведу.

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
var internalUri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.10:8888/PService/");
var externalUri = new Uri("http://168.211.65.22:2145/PService/");

var client = new FooClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(internalUri));
client.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new ClientViaBehavior(externalUri));
```

Как я уже писал, адреса предпочтительнее задавать в конфиге. Для клиента это делается так:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication.IFoo" address="http://192.168.1.10:8888/PService/" behaviorConfiguration="foo" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="foo">
          <clientVia viaUri="http://168.211.65.22:2145/PService/" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Как видно, уже чуть сложнее чем для сервера но все еще ничего страшного.

---

Также допустим смешанный вариант. Дело в том, что от адреса конечной точки совершенно не требуется чтобы он был настоящим http-адресом! Все реальные http-адреса указываются в атрибутах `listenUri` и `viaUri`, к адресу же главное требование - совпадение у клиента и у сервера. А значит, туда можно написать любой uri, например какой-нибудь `urn:local:my-cool-web-service` (такой адрес обычно называют логическим адресом сервиса).

Вот пример конфигов для сервера и клиента с настроенным логическим адресом:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApplication.Foo">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication.IFoo" address="urn:local:foo" listenUri="http://192.168.1.10:8888/PService/" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication.IFoo"  address="urn:local:foo" behaviorConfiguration="foo" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="foo">
          <clientVia viaUri="http://168.211.65.22:2145/PService/" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Достоинство этого варианта - ни клиент ни сервер ничего не знают о деталях трансляции адресов. Недостаток же этого варианта заключается в том, что если вы покажите такой конфиг стороннему разработчику, он может, э-э-э... слегка удивиться такому решению.

---

Наконец, самый последний вариант. Самый простой, но костыль. Можно вовсе отключить проверку адреса на стороне сервера:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
class Foo : IFoo { }
```

Comment: Павел, а это работает только для WS или на TcpBinding тоже будет работать? Там же по идее те же самые SOAP сообщения бегают, только упакованы немного иначе. Я про предпоследний вариант.

Comment: @rdorn там WS-Addressing не используется, так же как и в BasicHttpBinding